# Transferring AppX Package from Working Computer to Another

Tags: powershell, windows-10, packages

I have a computer with the version of the Photos app which has the ability to caption videos. I tried to update this app on the user's computer, but it wouldn't update or reinstall through the store. I tried removing it with get-appxpackage  | remove-appxpackage. That removed it, but still not able to update using the store.

I am now resorting to attempt transferring it from a computer which has the version to the user's computer.

I run the following to dump the manifest:

```
$manifest = Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package "Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2020.19111.24110.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
$manifest.innerXML > <path>\AppxManifest.xml
```

On the target:

```
Add-AppxPackage -register <path> -DisableDevelopmentMode
```

I get the message "Appx manifest invalid ... cannot switch the encoding type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not that simple, as you realized, the OS has a couple of security measures to ensure the integrity of the apps installed, I will not go into details as this is not the purpose of this question.

The only solution is to get your hands on the full appx/msix package. [You can download it using Fiddler](https://www.maketecheasier.com/download-appx-files-from-windows-store/).

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer. Currently I can't get into the store, but the user has since downloaded the app, we had to remove all the store policies from his computer and he managed to download it.